# How to plot the chart given in the figure with asteriks in java

Tags: java, charts

[image]

I am trying to obtain a chart like in the figure. I have a string array of names of months and corresponding numbers of asteriks in an integer array for each month(8 for May or -9 for March for example). I am trying to plot with this allignment. Values of asteriks for each month varies with given input. I don't know how to make this allignment.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first approach would be something like this:

```java
String[] names = new String[]{"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"};
int[] asterisks = new int[]{15, 17, -7, -9, 7, 13, 15};

int maxMinName = 0, maxMaxName = 0;
for (int asterisk : asterisks) {
  if (asterisk > maxMaxName) {
    maxMaxName = asterisk;
  }
  if (asterisk < maxMinName) {
    maxMinName = asterisk;
  }
}

final String fmt =
    "%" + Math.max(1, Math.abs(maxMinName)) +
    "s|%-" + Math.max(1, Math.abs(maxMaxName)) + "s %s";

for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  StringBuilder asterisk = new StringBuilder();
  for (int j = 0; j < Math.abs(asterisks[i]); j++) {
    asterisk.append('*');
  }

  if (asterisks[i] < 0) {
    System.out.println(String.format(fmt, asterisk, "", names[i]));
  } else {
    System.out.println(String.format(fmt, "", asterisk, names[i]));
  }
}
```

Produces:

```
         |***************   January
         |***************** February
  *******|                  March
*********|                  April
         |*******           May
         |*************     June
         |***************   July
```